# AS3 - Create an instance to access a method/function or use static [UPDATE - Some Benchmarking - added]

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, function, static, instantiation

**Noobie waffle &/or preamble:**

Okay, so this is my first question, for years SO has never failed in steering me in the right direction, nevertheless, I continue to be a poor, or mediocre at best wannabe programmer and still continue to find basic questions rattling around in my cavernous and echoing head. This question is one of those, but for once I cannot find the specific answer there are lots of tangential questions and parallel discussions, but not anything that I perceive to be answering this one as gives me a clearer understanding.

So, without further ado...

**The question:**

What is quicker (and/or best practice); making a class function which is static and as a result callable from anywhere else in the package, or instantiating that class when and where you wish to use it and subsequently referring to the instance function?

Everything I have read up to now, points to static being slower than instance functions/variables in general, but what I am battling with, is there not a cost in first instantiating a class, just to access one element of it.

It seems the act of instantiating should come with a cost in MS in addition to the subsequent accessing of the property you wish to use, which using ClassName.function(); doesn't, meaning the static route would be faster is this correct? And either way, by how much? Would it noticeable on something that was only called on a click, or something called no more than at a rate of an ENTER_FRAME event?

As well as speed, is there not a memory cost to instantiating a class, like buying a multipack of crisps when you only wanted one packet, which you could have gotten straight from the shelf, this may be better value in the long run, but if you only ever eat that one packet of crisps, it actually turns out more costly, and what's more it took up more room in your trolley, meaning less room for other goodies, no fizzy pop for me :( I'm not really sure if that analogy helped...

Anyway, I'm going to start trying to benchmark this myself, but in the meantime it seems like it might be a simple answer for those in the know (those much more knowledgeable and experienced than me), and that being so if it is, I would greatly appreciate some insight, if you have it to give.

So far, [this](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/413) has come closest to answering my question, but I'm having trouble extracting the specific answer to my question, perhaps it is my lack of understanding that is the route cause, and the answer is there already.

**To recap for TLDR and time saving;**

1. What is quicker/best practice; Calling a static function or instantiating a class and then calling the instance function?
2. Is the cost of first instantiating a class, just to access one element of it considered?
3. For the faster route, by how much is it faster?
4. Would it noticeable on something that was only called on a click, or on ENTER_FRAME?
5. As well as speed, is there not a higher memory cost to instantiating an entire class, as opposed to just referencing it through static?

If you have time to answer, I'd like to thank you in advance.

**[EDIT]**

Okay, So I ran a quick test, I have kind of answered my question, but still think best practice and other peoples opinions would benefit my learning. (See test below.

Okay, so I have two classes, main doc class and another class.

**Main.as**

```
    import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class Main extends Sprite
{       
    private static var preInstancedOtherClass:OtherClass = new OtherClass();
    private var averageOf:int = new int(10);
    public function Main()
    {
        runTests();
    }

    private function runTests() : void
    {
        var msRuntime1:Number = 0;
        var msRuntime2:Number = 0;
        var msRuntime3:Number = 0;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < averageOf; i++)
        {
            msRuntime1 += test1();
            msRuntime2 += test2();
            msRuntime3 += test3();

        }
        trace("static function ex-time: " + (msRuntime1/averageOf));
        trace("instance function ex-time: " + (msRuntime2/averageOf));
        trace("preInstance function ex-time: " + (msRuntime3/averageOf));
    }

    private function test1() : Number
    {
        var start_time:int = getTimer();
        OtherClass.testFunc1();
        return (getTimer()-start_time);
    }

    private function test2() : Number
    {
        var start_time:int = getTimer();
        var instanceofOtherClass:OtherClass = new OtherClass();
        instanceofOtherClass.testFunc2();
        return (getTimer()-start_time);
    }

    private function test3() : Number
    {
        var start_time:int = getTimer();
        preInstancedOtherClass.testFunc2();
        return (getTimer()-start_time);
    }
}
```

**OtherClass.as**

```
    import flash.display.Sprite;

public class OtherClass extends Sprite
{
    private var testLoop:int = new int(1000000);
    private static var staticTestLoop:int = new int(1000000);

    public function OtherClass() : void
    {
        //Do naffink
    }

    public static function testFunc1() : void
    {
        var testInt:int = 0;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < staticTestLoop; i++)
        {
            testInt += 10;
        }
    }

    public function testFunc2() : void
    {
        var testInt:int = 0;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < testLoop; i++)
        {
            testInt += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Results:**

So I kind of answered the majority of my question. After running 10 tests, it appears that static is on average faster 9/10 times, albeit not by much, so should I use the static function method? It makes things harder as it can only access static vars, but for utility classes it might save some time.

Is there a better(OOP) and much faster way completely?

Does this small MS time saving matter? will it ad up to much, or become even bigger with more worthwhile and complex operations, more testing needed or a waste of my time at this point, I don't know?

**Here are the results:**

(rep too low to post an image)

**Static**
70.3    70.5    71.5    71  70.5    71.2    71.4    77.4    72.7    70.2

**Instantiated**
71.9    73.5    73.7    73.8    73.7    70.9    73.4    77.9    74.9    73.4

**Previously instantiated**
71.9    73.2    73.7    73.6    73.9    71  73.4    78.8    75.1    73.1

What I find interesting is that instantiating once at the start of the class is practically on a par with creating a new instance on the fly. So maybe this answers my question about inline instantiation, in saying that there's not much more overhead.

Thoughts would be appreciated, do such small differences matter, and are there better options?

Comment: Some people love to answer this kind of question ... They will be all wrong anyway since your question lack an essential element to make it relevant for any programming language: a context. In programming, a valid answer in one context might not be valid in another so asking that question without any context makes the question and any given answer completely irrelevant and useless. Voted Down

Comment: Thanks for the input BotMaster. I'm not sure the importance of Voting Up or Down, but thanks anyway :) With regards to context, I have several circumstances where I am trying to decide the best way to approach this, I thought there would be a general scope-free general practice rules of thumb that work regardless of scope. I wasn't asking this for the sake of it and the example I used is just that an example.

Comment: +1 for benchmarking yourself. Is there a specific reason you do the runs like Method1, Method2, Method3, Method1, Method2, Method3 instead of 10xMethod1, 10xMethod2, 10xMethod3?

Comment: Thanks, and no particular reason other than I threw it together quickly, in my hasty first attempt at benchmarking.

Comment: Also, @ Pimgd & Daniel MesSer & thank you for the answers folks, I'm taking some time to fully digest and understand before coming up with my selection. There's lots of good information there, it's going to help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Since question lacks a proper context, I'm assuming some kind of general context here. As is always the case with these things, test for your specific case to see what works best for you.**

> To recap for TLDR and time saving;
>
> What is quicker/best practice; Calling a static function or instantiating a class and then calling the instance function?

You've already solved quicker, it seems. As for best practice... All pure functions (no I/O, and given same input, same output) should be statically called. Like you do with `Math`. `Math.random()` is the exception here. If you need to hold some state, however, you're better off instantiating the class.

> Is the cost of first instantiating a class, just to access one element of it considered?

Vaguely worded, so lets rephrase: "Did I consider the performance cost in my answer to the first question?" Yes, I did. And I immediately discarded its impact on my answer. In a loop where you're gonna need such a function multiple times, you move instantiation outside the loop as an almost natural optimization. The only case that remains is regular, single use - and at that point it no longer matters. Stop micro-optimizations until you need it - spend time on development instead, so that when you DO need the extra performance, you can string a bunch of performance gains after another (setting up benchmark environment properly is troublesome work and best done once).

For instance. You're mixing numeric types `Number` and `int` in your code. That takes conversion. That's a performance hit. How big? You'd have to test. But it's usually the case that if you start worrying about these small optimizations, you're missing the bigger ones.

> For the faster route, by how much is it faster?

Apparently, by 2 milliseconds, on your testing environment.

> Would it noticeable on something that was only called on a click, or on ENTER_FRAME?

No. At 30 FPS, you have 33.3ms available. At 60 FPS, you have 16.6ms available. 2 ms fits in there easily.

> As well as speed, is there not a higher memory cost to instantiating an entire class, as opposed to just referencing it through static?

Memory cost?
For classes?
Another thing that you should just not worry about (and if you DO wish to know, test it...)
Objects eat far more memory. In specific, collections of objects.
In games, that would be all the tiles for a level, or all the enemies, all the graphics... such things take far, far, far more memory.

In short...

**Most of these things just don't matter, unless you have to work on a very old device, or have a performance/memory issue (and have already exhausted flaws on a design-level!)**

Comment: Firstly, I hadn’t spotted the conversion, I like to think I’d have spotted it along the way (returning an int when the return type is a number meaning it needs to be converted. I can obviously see how that is costly, and think it boils down to me making that in a hurry. Anyway, good catch!
With regards to optimization, as I mentioned in my other post, it’s not unwarranted optimization, but in hindsight mostly misguided, as it may just be a case of managing what is running when the ANEs are called, optimization in design rather than micro managing code.

Comment: So I suppose, to eke out performance from a poorly designed engine is a waste of time, rebuild the engine better, strip it down and put the things in the right place would be better… I do admittedly do have design flaws in my codebase and am working to iron them out.
Re: Memory cost/classes/objects [Facepalm – good point, bold typeface ceertainly warranted]
I like both answers, they have pointed out serious flaws in my thinking and opened my eyes a bit, but I am selecting your answer as you specifically addressed the posed questions.

Thanks again for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: voted down. The question has no context and as a result all answers are irrelevant. You just couldn't resist, could you?

Comment: @BotMaster I tried my best to answer the question whilst keeping an open mind about having a vague context. That's why each statement I made has a disclaimer (like at the bottom!). Also with usage of probably, usually, and other words that mean "not always".

Comment: Obviously you knew the question was bad but you had to answer anyway.

Comment: @BotMaster I didn't really care about the question's quality - I cared that there was someone that was willing to learn - willing enough to even write their own benchmark! But they're still left with questions. It might not perfectly fit the Q/A format of StackOverflow anymore, but it helps at least 1 person learn, and that's what matters for me.

Comment: I'm also thinking about people searching for solutions for their own problem. They might read the contextless question, read your answer and skip the disclaimer and implement the worst possible solution for their situation.

Comment: @BotMaster Any recommendations to make them "not-skip" the disclaimer? Maybe I should put it at the top.

Comment: Before your answer, point out that the question is missing a context and that any true answer to that type of question should depend on context. For any given problem those answers can be different.

Comment: I think I did such a thing, given how the post reads now. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Without anything to back my claims (short version): You should use static if stuff is instance independent since it makes it easier for flash to handle it correctly... and you as a person should never bother with CPU performance related to this area or similar "micro optimization" areas unless you have an application that needs optimization in order to function properly since almost everything in this area is more dependent on "the bigger picture" rather than how you handle a specific code line.

Here's a more verbose answer consisting of random thoughts:

AS3 is a dynamic language that achieves "decent performance" due to it not applying every code line just as you thought it would or just as you wrote it. There are tons of extra layers between the code you write and the actual code running in the end on a specific computer.

Add to it a layer of garbage collector that might, or might not create a new instance or reserve new memory when you type "new Foobar()" depending on what it has in it's cache, when it was last collected if application is running low on it's allocated memory, if it happens to be a Sunday or a Thursday.

Also you need to understand that your test where you compare two timestamps are "not very reliable". Anything else happening on computer (other applications, I/O, OS CPU managment + bazillion other reasons) could tip this in any way. You could get a small indication towards something being better or worse given enough test cases but that's all.

Also, you should know that you could receive completely different results by running the function `test2()` before `test1()` etc.

Also any result you find here might be completely different if applied to another running environment. (Environment in this case referring to: CPU-architecture, Runtime executable, memory budget, browser, SSD-disk/non SSD, flash global settings and other stuff)

This is my point: For your specific case, the runtime might notice that you are "constantly creating/recreating a class" and decide to alter machine code to not create/delete object. It might decide to inline your function calls. It might decide to change "global" for-loop calling functions into a inlined for-loop where it is just iterating on 3 local variables. That's the beauty and bane of a dynamic language (and same rule could be applied to assembly code running on different CPU-architectures...)

Comment: Using Static to make it easier for flash to handle something not requiring an instance correctly, sounds logical and good.
Re: needing optimization, I have an app that slowed down considerably when I added some ANEs, so I’m looking to optimize/refactor my code, as I’ve learned a lot since I started (still have a mountain to climb!)
After the app snowballed, a lot was lost in the bigger picture as features crept in and bells and whistles were layered on to its detriment I suppose. So optimizing is where I am at, and it seems that requires much more learning and improvement of my practices.

Comment: Also, the information about the behaviour of AS3 and its dynamic nature that’s very interesting and something I’d not known/considered.
With regards to my hasty benchmark, I can definitely see flaws in my logic there now, but I wanted to contribute what I could to the thread. Again, your breakdown makes a lot of sense.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. :)